# All activities have an error: cannot not be resolved to type

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my first attempt at making an app, I was making the interfaces and got this error on all my activities activity_activityname cannot be resolved to a type. I have cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times now and none of the solutions I have researched have helped.

```
package com.kev.runningdiary;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.R;
import android.R.layout; 


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `import android.R` and `android.R.layout`(you want R to reference your own package not from android system)

after removing press  Alt+Shift+O (or Cmd+Shift+O in OS X) (thats a quick shortcut to fix imports) when prompted which R class to include select the one from the local package

if that doesn't work (which probably means that your R class was deleted) try one of the fixes from this SO answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855902/616606

Comment: I removed the R imports, Now there is an error with R. cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, Alt+Shift+O (or Cmd+Shift+O in OS X) will attempt to automatically add the correct imports for you - it should ask if you want to import the R class from the Android library or from your com.kev.runningdiary package - choose the latter.

Comment: thanks @EricBrynsvold i was trying to get eclipse up on my end so i can look up the shortcut

Comment: My R class isn't in the gen package, It deleted itself. From the research I have done, R will delete itself if resources aren't named in lower-case. But all my resources have lower case lettering.

Comment: @Josh, no problem, I use it all the time, so was able to come up with it off the top of my head...haha.

Comment: None of those suggestions worked unfortunately, I think I will just start the project again. Thanks for your help Josh and Eric.