# My r.java file is missing

Tags: android, sdk, android-2.2-froyo, r.java-file

Recently I updated my Eclipse and I found that my r.java file to be missing. 
I even tried to rename all file in the resource folder to lowercase and cleaned the project .
Then even checked the Android version in  java build path. 
Please someone help me to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

The R.java file may fail to build if there is an error in an XML file. Also, according to @superM, menus may also cause this problem. Look at this thread for more info:

[Missing R.java file even though project cleaned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649357/missing-r-java-file-even-though-project-cleaned)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you dont have any XML errors in your layouts
Check to make sure you dont have any errors in your strings/colors/values xml files
Check to make sure that you dont have any res items with a file size of 0 (this was my most recent case)