# Don't found method so regen the file R.java

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I'm starting to program android Apps with eclipse. At the start all is Ok but after a week in all projects the file R.java was taked off and all projects not work. I search for mthods to regen it also here but any method that i try not work (clean, build automatically, Right click>preferences>java build path). Nothing work and i don't know how to solve (i also reinstall sdk and eclipse, only sdk....) The space in the local disc is sufficient to take all datas. How can i solve? Thanks you!

http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1047/Ngegx7.jpg

Comment: Create a new project and transfer your files there.

Comment: Also if i create a new project, it starts without R.java class....

Comment: There is probably an error with your Eclipse environment, have you tried restarting eclipse?

Comment: I also tried to reinstall eclipse and sdk...not only restart...:D

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your folder's tree? The one on the package explorer section

Comment: Yeah sure...i post it in the principale answer (watch up)

Comment: See here, to see if that method works http://stackoverflow.com/a/22758404/4324834 the error might also be coming from the other projects in your workspace so to make sure that everything is ok start with a new project and no other projects in the same workspace.

Comment: I try...i also have open only one project (the others are close) but nothing...the file R.java not regen and it contineu to giv eme the error

Comment: You mentioned that Build Automatically is enabled right?

Comment: Now no..in a guide i find it and i try also to uncheck and to retry...but nothing

Comment: If you want to send me your project I can probably take a look

Comment: the problem is that all projects that i create or import have that problem...

Comment: There are so many possible answers, error in xml file, a library is missing in the project, drawable images are named in an unsupported format (my_drawable.png instead of my-drawable.png)m It's very hard to know what the problem might be, hit the panic button. Restart your computer, open eclipse, remove all your projects, change workspace, etc.. start from zero which I know you probably already did.

Comment: try to create a project that uses a newer API, like 19 and above and don't use the supporting library

Comment: for those projects i use only API 19...for all :D

Comment: i don't know how to solve..i can't restore the Operative System....

Comment: Wow, It seems more complicated than normal, you might consider a switch to https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: i will try....the projects in Android Studio have the same structure then eclipse and i can import them normally?

Comment: Android Studio is a whole new interface which can be sometimes confusing and cause headaches but once you get the hang of it you'll see how amazing it is, specially now that is not on BETA anymore so you can start fresh developing on a stable environment. Please read this which will help you migrate properly from eclipse to AS https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 1):

R files are automatically generated when project is built (like how you are doing clean - build). However, a common reason for R being not generated is when there is some error in your layout xml or etc. after cleaning (removing all generated stuff) the project.

Try to check the last place you edited and see if there is no error.

Comment: I haven't errors...the unique error that i have is the R class that isn't found. And the R file is taked off also in projects that the days before were working. I didn't modify them and one day the R class was disappear. An other projects that i create start without the R class and i can't do anything (when i create a new project i start without the R

Comment: Try double checking all your XML files and check that at the top it says <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. Also triple check that they are all spelt right. That was what my problem was